# Azure Blob Move folders inside same container C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

i have to move/copy from the source folder to destination folder, i'm following the below C# code,  Does it even copy the folders too ? can you please confirm

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
var destContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");

var sourceFilePath = "hhh/www/";
var destFilePath = "hhh/jjj/";
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFilePath);
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destFilePath);
await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Does it even copy the folders too ?`? Your code will copy `hhh/www/hello.txt` blob to `hhh/jjj/hello.txt` blob.

Comment: i was in a impression that the above code will support copying the folders .  do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: The above code will only work for a single blob.

Comment: there's no folders on Azure Storage, there's a container, then the following is part of the blob name

Comment: As Gaurav Mantri said in the comment, azure blob storage is actually a flat structure(there is no folder in it.). But in fact, you can design what you need by yourself. I wrote an example.

Comment: I posted an answer, if it answered your question, can you [accept it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ1gS.png) to end this question?:)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, there is no folders' concept on Azure blob storage. Have a look at the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction):

> Blob storage offers three types of resources:
>
> - The storage account
> - A container in the storage account
> - A blob in a container

You could Copy and move **blobs** from one container or storage account to another, have a look at this tutorial:
[Copy and move blobs from one container or storage account to another from the command line and in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/)

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav Mantri said in the comment, azure blob storage is actually a flat structure(there is no folder in it.).

`'filepath'+'filename'='blobname'`

But you can design code such as below to achieve your requirement:

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Copyfiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceconnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxxxcore.windows.net";
            string sinkconnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=xxxxxxcore.windows.net";
            string sourcefilepath = "source/f1";
            string sinkfilepath = "sink/f1";

            BlobServiceClient sourceblobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sourceconnectionString);
            BlobServiceClient sinkblobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sinkconnectionString);

            //Copy files.
            Copyfiles(sourceblobServiceClient, sinkblobServiceClient, sourcefilepath, sinkfilepath);

        }
        static List<string> Getfilesname(Pageable<BlobItem> blobs, List<string> subs3)
        {

            //Below code can get the path.
            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                string[] sub_names = blob.Name.Split('/');
                if (sub_names.Length > 1 && !subs3.Contains(sub_names[sub_names.Length - 1]))
                {
                    subs3.Add(sub_names[sub_names.Length - 1]);
                }
            }
            return subs3;
        }

        static string[] Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix(string folderpath)
        {
            string test = folderpath;
            //
            string[] sub_names = test.Split('/');
            string containername = sub_names[0];
            string blobnameprefix = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sub_names.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    blobnameprefix = blobnameprefix + sub_names[i] + "/";
                }
            }
            string[] all = new string[2];
            all[0] = containername;
            all[1] = blobnameprefix;
            return all;
        }

        static string[] Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix2(string folderpath)
        {
            string test = folderpath;
            //
            string[] sub_names = test.Split('/');
            string containername = sub_names[0];
            string blobnameprefix = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sub_names.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    blobnameprefix = blobnameprefix + sub_names[i] + "/";
                }
            }
            string[] all = new string[2];
            all[0] = containername;
            all[1] = blobnameprefix;
            return all;
        }
        static string getsuffixblobnameofsinkblob(string sourcepath, string sourceblobname)
        {
            string suffixblobname = "";
            string[] sourcepatharray = sourcepath.Split("/");
            int needtodelete = sourcepatharray.Length - 1;
            string[] spdblobname = sourceblobname.Split('/');
            for (int i = 0 + needtodelete; i < spdblobname.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == spdblobname.Length - 1)
                {
                    suffixblobname = suffixblobname + spdblobname[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    suffixblobname = suffixblobname + spdblobname[i] + "/";
                }
            }
            return suffixblobname;
        }
        static void Copyfiles(BlobServiceClient sourceblobServiceClient, BlobServiceClient sinkblobServiceClient, string sourcefilepath, string sinkfilepath)
        {

            string sourcecontainername = Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix(sourcefilepath)[0];
            string sourceblobnameprefix = Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix(sourcefilepath)[1];
            string sinkcontainername = Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix(sinkfilepath)[0];
            string sinkblobnameprefix = Getcontainernameandblobnameprefix(sinkfilepath)[1];
            List<string> sourcefiles = new List<string>();
            BlobContainerClient sourcecontainerClient = sourceblobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourcecontainername);
            BlobContainerClient sinkcontainerClient = sinkblobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sinkcontainername);
            Pageable<BlobItem> sourceblobs = sourcecontainerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: sourceblobnameprefix);
            List<string> sourcefilesname = Getfilesname(sourceblobs, sourcefiles);


            //Below code can get the file name.
            foreach (var sourcefile in sourcefiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----");
                Console.WriteLine(sourcefile);
                Console.WriteLine("----");
            }

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var sourceblob in sourceblobs)
            {
                var sourceblobclient = sourcecontainerClient.GetBlobClient(sourceblob.Name);
                BlobDownloadInfo download = sourceblobclient.Download();
                Stream sourcestream = download.Content;
                var sinkblobclient = sinkcontainerClient.GetBlobClient(sinkblobnameprefix + getsuffixblobnameofsinkblob(sourcefilepath, sourceblob.Name));
                sinkblobclient.Upload(sourcestream);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake" Version="12.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```